# Raspberry OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat

Tags: node.js, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to run https://github.com/drejkim/face-detection-node-opencv on a RPI3 for a school project.

I succesfully installed opencv 2.4.9 and the node-face-detection but I got an error when i'm trying to access to the cam (raspi-cam ) from another pc in the same network :

> HTTP server listening on port 8080
>
> VIDIOC_QBUF: Invalid argument
>
> VIDIOC_QBUF: Invalid argument
>
> VIDIOC_QBUF: Invalid argument
>
> OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat, file /build/opencv-ISmtkH/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 2482
>
> OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat, file /build/opencv-ISmtkH/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 2482
>
> OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat, file /build/opencv-ISmtkH/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 2482
>
> /home/pi/face-detection-node-opencv-master/server/lib/routes/socket.js:24
>           if (err) throw err;
>                    ^
>
> Error: /build/opencv-ISmtkH/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/core/src/array.cpp:2482: error: (-206) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat

The pc is able to load the html and css code, but didn't load the video flux.

So i've tried with another laptop, i'm able to run it and access to his webcam with another pc on the same network. Like i would do with the RPI3.

Thanks for helping and sorry for my english, it isn't my native language.

Answer (score 1):

Try to **reduce**

```
camFps=5 
// and 
camInterval=2000.
```

It **works**.